# Integration with reciprocal

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac1{y-y^2}\,dy$$
Not sure how to do.

I tried substitution, not sure if product rule would work?

Comment: 3 different methods are exposed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618295/integral-of-product-of-two-inverse-polynomials/2618389#2618389

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integral of product of two inverse polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618295/integral-of-product-of-two-inverse-polynomials)

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Can you find $a$ and $b$ so that
$$\frac1{y-y^2}=\frac1{y(1-y)}=\frac ay+\frac b{y-1}\ ?$$

Comment: Exactly... Partial fraction decomposition

Answer (score 0):

Try completing the square. $$\frac{1}{y-y^2} = \frac{1}{-\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}}$$

Now substitute $u = y-\frac{1}{2}$.